# File/Access Error when trying to call a VB6 application from c#

Tags: c#, vb6

```
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + "MyExecutable.exe");            
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;            
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;


        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
```

I have an executable in my project, say "MyExecutable.exe". When running this application, it will create a log file in the same path where this `exe` is executed.

If I run this `exe` in command prompt, I have no issues.

But If I run the exe from c# code, it is throwing error "File/Access Error" in the below code which is in `MyExecutable.exe`

```
Open `sLogfile` For Output Access Write As `LogFileNumber`
```

where `sLogfile` is the `logfile` name and `LogFileNumber` is the `FreeFile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current guidance says to not write logs into an executable directory. This is probably Windows enforcing this guidance. Write to the user's `AppData` directory instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After changing the log file path to Temp directory, there is no issue. But do we have any msdn link which states not to write logs in the executable directory?

Comment: @Rayner Windows has been enforcing that type of restriction since at least Vista in 2007. Remember how old VB6 is, many VB6 programs were born in the days of the Wild West when anything was permitted (if not encouraged) by Windows.

Comment: The specific restriction your program probably ran into is that unless it runs as admin, it *cannot* write into Program Files. So this is less of a "should not" scenario than a "cannot". I think the reasons not to have programs randomly modifying files in Program Files is pretty obvious.;